# Equivalence of the condition that the supremum of i.i.d. RVs are finite a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am proving the following :

Suppose $\{X_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are i.i.d. random variables. Then $P(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n < \infty) = 1$ if and only if $ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{P(X_n > M)} < \infty$ for some $M>0.$

I guess by the form of the problem, that Borel-Canteli lemma will be used at some point, but I could not thought of a good way to connect it to the problem.

Any idea or hint will be really helpful. Thanks.

(edit)

Assume $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{P(X_n > M)} < \infty.$ In fact, as they are i.i.d., $P(X_n > M) = P(X_1>M)$ for all $n.$ Thus $P(X_1>M) = 0$ and $P(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n > M) \le \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{P(X_n > M)} = 0.$

Conversely, I've realized that $\{sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{X_n} < \infty\} = \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X_n \le m\}.$

Comment: Are you sure the random variables $(X_n)$ are supposed to be i.i.d., **or only independent**?

Comment: I am 100 % sure that they are supposed to be i.i.d., as it was exam problem.

Comment: Well then the exam is slightly absurd, but why not.

Comment: You're right Did. Now I understand independence is enough, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $P(\sup_n X_n < \infty) = 1$.  Since $\{\sup_n X_n < \infty\} = \bigcup_{M=1}^\infty \{\sup_n X_n \le M\}$, we have $\lim_{M \to \infty} P(\sup_n X_n \le M) = 1$.
But if $P(X_i > M) > 0$, $P(\sup_n X_n > M) = 1$.  So for some $M$ we must have $P(X_i > M) = 0$.

Conversely, if $P(\sup_n X_n < \infty) < 1$, then for all $M$ we have $P(\sup_n X_n > M) > 0$,
and $P(X_i > M) > 0$.

Comment: How do you go from $P[X_i >M] >0$ to $P[\sup_n X_n >M]  = 1$?

Comment: Second Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: Using the fact that $X_n$ are iid, I see. Thanks.